# scikit Mixtypes of Y error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hi I'm a scikit newbie here. I'm trying to train the computer that given an array of float decide between the 3 classes. I was classifying the classes as 0, 0.5, and 1. I also tried 0, 1.0, and 2.0 . I still get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 85, in     unique_labels
raise ValueError("Mix type of y not allowed, got types %s" % ys_types)
ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types set(['continuous', 'multiclass'])
```

I have no idea what that error means

Comment: Would be much better if you could add some code. Ideally something we can paste directly into an interpreter and see the error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using integer types for your target labels. Or, perhaps better, use string labels like `['a', 'b', 'c']` but with more descriptive names.

If you check the code for this file `multiclass.py` ([code is here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py)) and look for the function `type_of_target`, you'll see that it is well-documented for this case.

Because some of the data are treated as `float` type (when `0.5` is included), it will believe you've got continuous-valued outputs, which won't do for multiclass discrete classification.

On the other hand, it will look at `[0, 1.0, 2.0]` like it is one integer and two `floats`, which is why you get both `continuous` and `multiclass`. Switching the last example to `[0, 1, 2]` should work. The documentation also makes it sound like switching to `[0.0, 1.0. 2.0]` would also work, but be careful and test that first.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell for sure without the code, but my guess is that the shape of your y data is not what is expected.

For example when my code threw this error it was because I was trying to pass y data into classification_report in the shape of (60000, 10, 2) when it was expecting it to be in the shape of (60000, 10)

I was re-running cells where I called to_categorical(y_test) more than once... When I loaded my code into a proper script and ran it it worked fine :)